# Does semantic-release have a replacer to replace a string in a file?

Tags: semantic-release

I was surprised not to see a plugin for semantic-release to do replacing of strings (e.g., by regex) within files, e.g., to update the version string in a service-worker (as well as README).

Does semantic-release have such a feature or plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official plugin to do that.
You can use a npm script or [@semantic-release/exec](https://github.com/semantic-release/exec) to run a script that do the replacement during the `prepare` step.

See [How can I use a npm build script that requires the package.json’s version ?](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/support/faq#how-can-i-use-a-npm-build-script-that-requires-the-package-jsons-version).